# Service return empty promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have service in which I simulate http request.

e.g.
I have array of object users:

```
var users = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Name1',
    groupId: 2
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Name2',
    groupId: 1
}];
```

And I have function which ask for it:

```
this.getUser = function(userId) {
    return this._returnLater(users.filter(function(user) {
        return user.id === userId;
    })[0]).then(angular.copy);
};
```

and use function `returnLater` which basicly just set timeout randomly

```
this._returnLater= function(response) {
    return $timeout(function() {
        return response;
    }, Math.random() * 2000);
};
```

This looks well for me. However If I try to run this code from my directive as:

```
var promise = UserService.getUser(1);
promise.then(function(res) {
  aeCtrl.user = res;
});
```

my `aeCtrl.user` is empty, if I try to `console.log(promise)` before `promise.then`i get this:

[image]

Is here someone who can advise me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you are facing, check [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NhPTEDrXd8xUDXJkxApq?p=preview). Before `promise.then` promise will have promise object only, you will get response in that `.then` function only when ajax succeeded ..

Comment: You receive the user but at the `then` stage you pass it to `angular.copy` function as an argument and the `getUser()` function returns the promise returned by the `then` stage which, when resolved will carry whatever it is the return value of `angular.copy(filteredUser)`

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to return a new promise and resolve it in the timeout

```
this._returnLater= function(response) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
        $timeout(function() {
            resolve(response);
        }, Math.random() * 2000);
    });
};
```

Comment: Hey @mrstebo thanks for answer. Unfortunately console.log promise return http://www.upnito.sk/0/nuch26aff72a5gpvp2dhhhhf6cu9rzm4.PNG console.log(res) = undefined :(

Comment: $timeout is a promise itself. Packing it into another promise (especially  native promise) is antipattern.

Comment: Good point @estus sir, it wouldn't help to run digest cycle as well.